# ReactJS - Add custom event listener to component

Tags: reactjs

In plain old HTML I have the DIV

```
<div class="movie" id="my_movie">
```

and the following javascript code

```js
var myMovie = document.getElementById('my_movie');
myMovie.addEventListener('nv-enter', function (event) {
     console.log('change scope');
});
```

Now I have a React Component, inside this component, in the render method, I am returning my div. How can I add an event listener for my custom event? (I am using this library for TV apps - [navigation](https://github.com/ahiipsa/navigation) )

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MovieItem extends Component {

  render() {

    if(this.props.index === 0) {
      return (
        <div aria-nv-el aria-nv-el-current className="menu_item nv-default">
            <div className="indicator selected"></div>
            <div className="category">
                <span className="title">{this.props.movieItem.caption.toUpperCase()}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    else {
      return (
        <div aria-nv-el className="menu_item nv-default">
            <div className="indicator selected"></div>
            <div className="category">
                <span className="title">{this.props.movieItem.caption.toUpperCase()}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

}

export default MovieItem;
```

Update #1:

[image]

I applied all the ideas provided in the answers. I set the navigation library to debug mode and I am able to navigate on my menu items only based on the keyboard (as you can see in the screenshot I was able to navigate to Movies 4) but when I focus an item in the menu or press enter, I dont see anything in the console.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class MenuItem extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Pre-bind your event handler, or define it as a fat arrow in ES7/TS
    this.handleNVFocus = this.handleNVFocus.bind(this);
    this.handleNVEnter = this.handleNVEnter.bind(this);
    this.handleNVRight = this.handleNVRight.bind(this);
  }

  handleNVFocus = event => {
      console.log('Focused: ' + this.props.menuItem.caption.toUpperCase());
  }

  handleNVEnter = event => {
      console.log('Enter: ' + this.props.menuItem.caption.toUpperCase());
  }

  handleNVRight = event => {
      console.log('Right: ' + this.props.menuItem.caption.toUpperCase());
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).addEventListener('nv-focus', this.handleNVFocus);
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).addEventListener('nv-enter', this.handleNVEnter);
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).addEventListener('nv-right', this.handleNVEnter);
    //this.refs.nv.addEventListener('nv-focus', this.handleNVFocus);
    //this.refs.nv.addEventListener('nv-enter', this.handleNVEnter);
    //this.refs.nv.addEventListener('nv-right', this.handleNVEnter);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).removeEventListener('nv-focus', this.handleNVFocus);
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).removeEventListener('nv-enter', this.handleNVEnter);
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).removeEventListener('nv-right', this.handleNVRight);
    //this.refs.nv.removeEventListener('nv-focus', this.handleNVFocus);
    //this.refs.nv.removeEventListener('nv-enter', this.handleNVEnter);
    //this.refs.nv.removeEventListener('nv-right', this.handleNVEnter);
  }

  render() {
    var attrs = this.props.index === 0 ? {"aria-nv-el-current": true} : {};
    return (
      <div ref="nv" aria-nv-el {...attrs} className="menu_item nv-default">
          <div className="indicator selected"></div>
          <div className="category">
              <span className="title">{this.props.menuItem.caption.toUpperCase()}</span>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default MenuItem;
```

I left some lines commented because in both cases I am not able to get the console lines to be logged.

Update #2: This navigation library does not work well with React with its original Html Tags, so I had to set the options and rename the tags to use aria-* so it would not impact React.

```js
navigation.setOption('prefix','aria-nv-el');
navigation.setOption('attrScope','aria-nv-scope');
navigation.setOption('attrScopeFOV','aria-nv-scope-fov');
navigation.setOption('attrScopeCurrent','aria-nv-scope-current');
navigation.setOption('attrElement','aria-nv-el');
navigation.setOption('attrElementFOV','aria-nv-el-fov');
navigation.setOption('attrElementCurrent','aria-nv-el-current');
```

Comment: @The I am basically using the example from this file (https://github.com/ahiipsa/navigation/blob/master/demo/index.html)

Comment: You don't need to both pre-bind in your constructor (`this.handleNVEnter = this.handleNVEnter.bind(this)`) and use ES7 property initializers with arrow functions (`handleNVEnter = enter => {}`) because fat arrow functions are always bound. If you can use ES7 syntax just go with that.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. I Was able to fix the problem. I am going to accept your answer as I am now using your solution but I also had to do something else. Since the Nagivation library HTML tags dont play nice with React, I had to set the tag names in the lib configuration to use aria-* prefix, the problem is that the events were also triggered using the same prefix, so setting the event to aria-nv-enter did the trick! Its working fine now. Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend changing `aria-*` to `data-*` because ARIA attributes are from a standard set, you cannot make up your own. Data attributes can be more arbitrarily set to whatever you want.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

If you need to [handle DOM events not already provided by React](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#clipboard-events) you have to add DOM listeners after the component is mounted:

***Update:** Between React 13, 14, and 15 changes were made to the API that affect my answer. Below is the latest way using React 15 and ES7. See [answer history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36181732/revisions) for older versions.*

```js
class MovieItem extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    // When the component is mounted, add your DOM listener to the "nv" elem.
    // (The "nv" elem is assigned in the render function.)
    this.nv.addEventListener("nv-enter", this.handleNvEnter);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Make sure to remove the DOM listener when the component is unmounted.
    this.nv.removeEventListener("nv-enter", this.handleNvEnter);
  }

  // Use a class arrow function (ES7) for the handler. In ES6 you could bind()
  // a handler in the constructor.
  handleNvEnter = (event) => {
    console.log("Nv Enter:", event);
  }

  render() {
    // Here we render a single <div> and toggle the "aria-nv-el-current" attribute
    // using the attribute spread operator. This way only a single <div>
    // is ever mounted and we don't have to worry about adding/removing
    // a DOM listener every time the current index changes. The attrs 
    // are "spread" onto the <div> in the render function: {...attrs}
    const attrs = this.props.index === 0 ? {"aria-nv-el-current": true} : {};

    // Finally, render the div using a "ref" callback which assigns the mounted 
    // elem to a class property "nv" used to add the DOM listener to.
    return (
      <div ref={elem => this.nv = elem} aria-nv-el {...attrs} className="menu_item nv-default">
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

[Example on Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/abeall/pen/zweGxa?editors=0010)

Comment: You are misusing `findDOMNode`. In your case `var elem = this.refs.nv;` is enough.

Comment: @Pavlo `refs` gives me a React element (without any `addEventListener` function), not a DOM node.

Comment: @Pavlo Hm, you're right, it seems that this changed in v.14 (to return the DOM element instead of the React element as in v.13, which is what I am using). Thanks.

Comment: using `ref=` is discourage you should use the callback as example `<div ref={e => this.$e = e} />`

Comment: Why do I need to "Make sure to remove the DOM listener when the component is unmounted"? Is there any source that they will create a leak?

Comment: @ncubica Good point, `ref` usage changed again... I'll update the answer.

Comment: I don't know of a way to view answer history in SO; if there is can someone enlighten me?

Comment: @levininja Click the `edited Aug 19 at 6:19` text under the post, which takes you to [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36181732/revisions).

Comment: How do you dispatch event?

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu React doesn't provide any custom event dispatching API as you are expected to use callback props (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21951734/react-js-custom-events-for-communicating-with-parent-nodes)), but you can use standard DOM `nv.dispatchEvent()` if you need to.

Comment: React will create a new instance of the ref on every re-render instead of keeping it between renders so you would need to re-add the eventListener on `componentDidUpdate`.  You should use `useRef` instead.

Comment: what is CustomEvent?

Comment: Is it possible to use the DOM listener, ie the `addEventListener()` method, in the `useEffect ()` hook method instead of the original `componentDidMount ()` method ??

Comment: In the example, a ref to a `div` element is returned.  What if we're returning another React Component instead?  You can still get a ref, but Component doesn't seem to implement `addEventListener()`.  How to handle this case?

Answer (score 21):

You could use [componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount) and [componentWillUnmount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#unmounting-componentwillunmount) methods:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class MovieItem extends Component
{
    _handleNVEvent = event => {
        ...
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).addEventListener('nv-event', this._handleNVEvent);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).removeEventListener('nv-event', this._handleNVEvent);
    }

    [...]

}

export default MovieItem;
```

Comment: Hi @vbarbarosh, I updated the question with more details

Answer (score 4):

First off, custom events don't play well with React components natively. So you cant just say `<div onMyCustomEvent={something}>` in the render function, and have to think around the problem.

Secondly, after taking a peek at the documentation for the library you're using, the event is actually fired on `document.body`, so even if it did work, your event handler would never trigger.

Instead, inside `componentDidMount` somewhere in your application, you can listen to nv-enter by adding

```
document.body.addEventListener('nv-enter', function (event) {
    // logic
});
```

Then, inside the callback function, hit a function that changes the state of the component, or whatever you want to do.

Comment: Could you help elaborate on the reason why "custom events don't play well with React components natively"?

Comment: @codeful.element, this site has some info on that: https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/#react

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `dannyjolie` more detailed answer without need of component reference but using `document.body` reference.

First somewhere in your app, there is a component method that will create a new custom event and send it.
For example, your customer switch lang.
In this case, you can attach to the document body a new event :

```
setLang(newLang) {
    // lang business logic here
    // then throw a new custom event attached to the body :
    document.body.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("my-set-lang", {detail: { newLang }}));
  }
```

Once that done, you have another component that will need to listen to the lang switch event. For example, your customer is on a given product, and you will refresh the product having new lang as argument.

First add/remove event listener for your target component :

```
  componentDidMount() {
    document.body.addEventListener('my-set-lang', this.handleLangChange.bind(this));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.removeEventListener('my-set-lang', this.handleLangChange.bind(this));
  }
```

then define your component `my-set-langw` handler

```
  handleLangChange(event) {
    console.log("lang has changed to", event.detail.newLang);
    // your business logic here .. this.setState({...});
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using `React.createRef()` and `ref=this.elementRef` to get the DOM element reference instead of `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)`. This way you can get the reference to the DOM element as an instance variable.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class MenuItem extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.elementRef = React.createRef();
  }

  handleNVFocus = event => {
      console.log('Focused: ' + this.props.menuItem.caption.toUpperCase());
  }
    
  componentDidMount() {
    this.elementRef.addEventListener('nv-focus', this.handleNVFocus);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.elementRef.removeEventListener('nv-focus', this.handleNVFocus);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <element ref={this.elementRef} />
    )
  }

}

export default MenuItem;
```