# reactjs call specific function when page refreshed or closed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component like:

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'


class MyView extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('onbeforeunload', this.saveState())
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.saveState())
    }

    saveState() {
        alert("exiting")
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                Something
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default MyView
```

Here when a user refresh the page I want to call a specific funtion and when call is finished I want the page to be refreshed. Same when user closes the page.

In my above code I am adding an event listener `onbeforeunload` and calling a `saveState` function.

But here my `componentDidMount` is working normally. `onbeforeunload` and `saveState` function is called normally when page is loaded not when page is refreshed or exited.

What is wrong in here and how can I call specific funcitn or give alert when someone exits or refresh the page in react ?

In the above code

Comment: Try to remove window event listener, guess componentWillUnmount uses `window.on('beforeunload')` underneath

Answer (score 1):

Attach beforeunload event on top level component and on beforeunload event make render empty which will trigger componentWillUnmount of all child components.

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'

class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () =>{
          this.setState({appended:true});
      });
    }
    render() {
      if(this.state.appended){
        return false;
      }else{
        return (<MyView />)
      }
    }
}


class MyView extends Component {


  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.saveState()
  }

  saveState() {
    alert("exiting")
  }

  render() {

    return (
        <div>
            Something
        </div>
    )
  }

}

export default MyView
```

Hope this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180414/reactjs-add-custom-event-listener-to-component), try this syntax :

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('onbeforeunload', this.saveState)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.saveState)
}
```