# How to add scroll event in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to add an `onScroll` event on a table. This is what I've tried:

```
componentDidMount() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.table).addEventListener('scroll', this.listenScrollEvent);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.table).removeEventListener('scroll', this.listenScrollEvent);
}

listenScrollEvent() {
    console.log('Scroll event detected!');
}

render() {
    return (
        <table ref="table">
           [...]
        </table>
    )
}
```

I tried `console.log(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.table))` and I'm getting the correct result but scroll event is never fired at all. I looked in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180414/reactjs-add-custom-event-listener-to-component) but still failed. Any help would be so much appreciated.

Comment: Is table content overflowing table boundaries? It not, it won't scroll.

Comment: the container has `overflow: auto` that means the table is inside a frame(if I'm correct). I don't want to use the `window.addEventListener`

Comment: try add `display: block` to table.

Comment: For those who are implementing the same as mine but is using django, try using [django-el-pagination](http://django-el-pagination.readthedocs.io/en/latest/twitter_pagination.html). It has `paginateOnScroll` already.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to bind this to the element in context.

```
render() {
    return (
        <table ref="table" onScroll={this.listenScrollEvent.bind(this)}>
           [...]
        </table>
    )
}
```

Comment: If you use ES6 Class for creating component.

Comment: I already did at the constructor but still doesn't work. `constructor(props) {super(props); this.listenScrollEvent = this.listenScrollEvent.bind(this);}`

Comment: While this is generally useful, note that the `listenScrollEvent` method in the original question doesn't do anything with `this` so binding it is actually unnecessary.

Comment: Well this actually helps me for some reason. It is simple and to the point

Answer (score 6):

You can use `onScroll` attribute:

```
listenScrollEvent() {
    console.log('Scroll event detected!');
}

render() {
    return (
        <table onScroll={this.listenScrollEvent}>
           [...]
        </table>
    )
}
```

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/81Lujabv/

Comment: I thought putting `onScroll` event on an element is not enabled in react? o_0

Comment: I tried changing it to `onClick` and it works... now back to the problem of `onScroll`

Answer (score 6):

I was looking to do something similar. Adding the event listener to the window instead of the ReactDom.findDOMNode worked for me...

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScrollToElement);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScrollToElement);
}

handleScrollToElement(event) {
    console.log('Fired ' + event)
}
```

Comment: I suspect this is the correct answer even though the asker said he didn't want to use `window...` in the comments. Yet, in the comments he also failed to answer the first question of whether the table contents are overflowing. I suspect the answer is really "no" since no other answers work for him. He doesn't tell us much about his ultimate goal so I can only guess he's going for a fixed/absolute table that will never scroll except with `window`. I was having similar trouble at first until I got the hint that scroll only fires on objects that overflow, so I looked it up and, yup, that was it.

Comment: you can have more than 1 scrolling component on a window, so not so great.

Answer (score 1):

according to React documents(https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html),

> React events are named using camelCase, rather than lowercase.
>   You can set attributes as you do with pure HTML.

**HTML:**

```
<div onclick="..." onscroll="...">
  ...
</div>
```

**JSX:**

```
<div onClick={...} onScroll={...}>
  ...
</div>
```

you should create a wrapper block element which has fixed height to enable scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I had been finding a good solution to this problem. The following piece of code is working, where **the listener is just on the particular class/div** :
*React version is 16.0.0*

**First import** ReactDOM, `import ReactDOM from "react-dom";`

**Then** in the `class xyz extends Component` section

```
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
        vPos : 0
    }
    this.listenScrollEvent = this.listenScrollEvent.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.category_scroll).addEventListener('scroll', this.listenScrollEvent);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.category_scroll).removeEventListener('scroll', this.listenScrollEvent);
  }

  listenScrollEvent(event) {
    console.log('firee');
    this.setState({
        vPos: event.target.body.scrollTop
    });
  }
```

**After pasting** the above functions, in the `render()` method , whatever you want to name the `ref` method, you can do so, **make sure** the same name goes in the `findDOMNode` as well , i.e, `findDOMNode(this.refs.category_scroll)`:

```
<div onScroll={this.listenScrollEvent} ref="category_scroll">
...
</div>
```

---

.

.

If it's a **horizontall scroll**, then `event.currentTarget.scrollTop` works in the listenScrollEvent() function.

Answer (score -1):

Give this a try, added `.bind(this)` to `this.listenScrollEvent` when you pass it to the `addEventListener`.

```
   componentDidMount() {
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.table).addEventListener('scroll', this.listenScrollEvent.bind(this));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.table).removeEventListener('scroll', this.listenScrollEvent.bind(this));
    }

    listenScrollEvent() {
        console.log('Scroll event detected!');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <table ref="table">
               [...]
            </table>
        )
    }
```