# Detect scroll if scroll is inside div

Tags: reactjs

```
<div ref={options}>
   {content}
</div>
```

hello, how can I catch the scroll is inside the options div? Is there any hook for this?

Comment: [Yes there is a hook](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/src/useScroll.ts). [Docs](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useScroll.md)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325581/how-to-add-scroll-event-in-react-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325581/how-to-add-scroll-event-in-react-component) Check this answer

Comment: we have an inbuilt api for this (intersection observer).
check this out : https://css-tricks.com/a-few-functional-uses-for-intersection-observer-to-know-when-an-element-is-in-view/