# How to get data from global function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'am new in React so my question probably is easy to resolve. I made simple version of my code to illustrate my problem.

```
class ReactComponent extends Component {
    addToken(token){
        this.props.actionAddODToken(token);
    }

    render(){
        return (
        <div>
          <h1>this.props.token</h1>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {addOneDriveToken: state.addOneDriveToken}
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({...boundActionCreators}, dispatch);
}

function sendToComponent(data) {
    let data ="some string data";
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddDrive);
```

Unfortunately sendTo Component is global function because I get data from child popup.

```
window.opener.sendToComponent(data);
```

sendToComponent is fire after ReactComponent rendered. So my question is how to send data from a function to a component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use event listener for that purpose. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36181732/2315280) is a great answer on react and event listeners. Also there is [react-event-listener](https://github.com/oliviertassinari/react-event-listener) library that you can check out.

Answer (score 1):

You're using Redux, so the "correct" way is to send data into the Store and then pick it up using mapStateToProps. So in your child popup you need to do a dispatch action, rather than using a global e.g.

```
function ChildPopup({ handleSend }) {
   return (
      <div className='popup'>
          <button onClick={ handleSend }>Send</button>
      </div>
   );
} 

const mapPropsToDispatch = {
    handleSend() {     //this gets turned into a prop in your popup
        return {
            type: "SEND_TO_COMPONENT",
            valueToSendToComponent: "some string data"
        }; //this action will get dispatched to the store and you can handle with a reducer
    }
};

export default connect( undefined, mapPropsToDispatch )( ChildPopup );
```

Comment: OMG it's obvious. Thank you!

Comment: I have another problem. Popup is another page, so this popup created own store versions that is not shared with parent page

Comment: @KonradKluzek If Dunkan Thackers answer solved your original issue you should upvote and accept the answer. You can create a new question if you have more things you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a *very* simplified example of how to write component that asks for user input. You would then connect it to Redux so that it could dispatch the right action and store that data in the Redux state, which would make the data available to any component you want (if you connect it as well).

```js
const UserInputFetcher = ({onUserInput}) => {
 getUserInput()
   .then(onUserInput)
   .catch(error => console.log('Ooops, error:', error));
 return <p>Don't mind me. Look in the "console"</p>;
}

const getUserInput = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const userInput = window.prompt('Some input would be nice:');
    if(userInput) {
      resolve({ veryImportantUserData: userInput })
    } else {
      reject(new Error('User refused to give input'));
    }
  });
}

const fakeDispatchOfAction = userInput => {
  console.log('Dispatcing action with payload', userInput);
}

ReactDOM.render(<UserInputFetcher onUserInput={fakeDispatchOfAction} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```