# React event listener function not called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, addeventlistener

I'm trying to add an event listener to a SVG path in a React component. I followed a previous Stack Overflow answer ([How to access SVG elements with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753732/how-to-access-svg-elements-with-javascript)) that used an anonymous function, and that worked fine. When I tried to set the callback to a function defined inside the React component class, as in this Stack Overflow answer ([ReactJS - Add custom event listener to component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180414/reactjs-add-custom-event-listener-to-component)), the function is not called. Interestingly, if I make a reference to the function in the componentWillMount and use the reference, it works.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class ProcessMap extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.hover = this.hover.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const t = this.hover;
        let svg = document.getElementById("drawing-svg");
        svg.addEventListener("load", function() {
            let svgDoc = svg.contentDocument;
            let path1 = svgDoc.getElementById("path3372");
            //path1.addEventListener("click", this.hover, false); // this did not work
            path1.addEventListener("click", t, false); // this works
        });
    }

    hover() {
        console.log("hover");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <object id="drawing-svg" width="300" height="400" type="image/svg+xml" data="images/drawing.svg"></object>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: `this` inside `componentDidMount` is different from `this` inside the function called on the event.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't working since you are trying to use `this` inside a new regular `function()`, where `this` isn't the React component anymore.

#### ES6 SOLUTION

Replace

```
componentDidMount(){
    const t = this.hover;
    let svg = document.getElementById("drawing-svg");
    svg.addEventListener("load", function() {
        let svgDoc = svg.contentDocument;
        let path1 = svgDoc.getElementById("path3372");
        //path1.addEventListener("click", this.hover, false); // this did not work
        path1.addEventListener("click", t, false); // this works
    });
}
```

with an arrow function

```
componentDidMount(){
    const t = this.hover;
    let svg = document.getElementById("drawing-svg");
    svg.addEventListener("load", () => {
        let svgDoc = svg.contentDocument;
        let path1 = svgDoc.getElementById("path3372");
        path1.addEventListener("click", this.hover, false);
    });
}
```

#### ES5 SOLUTION

If you can't use ES6, then you can either keep track of `this` by storing it in a variable:

```
componentDidMount(){
    const t = this.hover;
    let svg = document.getElementById("drawing-svg");
    var that = this;
    svg.addEventListener("load", function() {
        let svgDoc = svg.contentDocument;
        let path1 = svgDoc.getElementById("path3372");
        path1.addEventListener("click", that.hover, false);
    });
}
```

Or use [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
componentDidMount(){
    const t = this.hover;
    let svg = document.getElementById("drawing-svg");
    svg.addEventListener("load", (function() {
        let svgDoc = svg.contentDocument;
        let path1 = svgDoc.getElementById("path3372");
        path1.addEventListener("click", this.hover, false);
    }).bind(this));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, all the solutions worked perfectly. A little embarrassed that I couldn't get it. Thank you again.

Comment: The way OP did it works too, just the line that is commented out doesn't. So don't think he actually needs to replace anything.