# Binding moved.zf.slider (Zurb Foundation) to React function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zurb-foundation

**Edit**: put in entire code as requested.  There are a few changes from the original.

I'm trying to use the foundation slider with react and ES6.  When the slider moves, it's supposed to [emit a moved.zf.slider event](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/slider.html#js-events).  React is supposed to be able to [bind to custom events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180414/reactjs-add-custom-event-listener-to-component#answer-36181732).  My code:

```
//React and third party references
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class SearchRangeFilter extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSliderMove = this.handleSliderMove.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.nv.addEventListener("moved.zf.slider", this.handleSliderMove);
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
        this.nv.removeEventListener('moved.zf.slider', this.handleSliderMove);
    }
    handleSliderMove(){
        console.log("Nv Enter:");
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="distance-selector-wrapper" className="flex-wrapper">
                <div className="range-slider__wrapper">
                <div ref={elem => this.nv = elem} className="slider" data-slider data-initial-start="50">
                    <span className="slider-handle"  data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1" aria-controls="sliderOutput1"></span>
                    <span className="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div className="range-slider__value">
                    <input type="number" id="sliderOutput1" />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default SearchRangeFilter;
```

By running `$("#sliderOutput1").val()` in my browser's console I can see that when I move the slider, the hidden input's value is changing.  However `handleSliderMove()` is never getting called.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please provide code for the entire component?

Comment: @TPorter updated

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are misusing the `refs` property. As defined in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), the refs property should be a callback. So in your case, your component definition would look like

```js
//...
<div 
  className="slider" 
  ref={elem => this.nv = elem}
  data-slider 
  data-initial-start="500" 
  data-start="0" 
  data-end="5000" 
  data-binding="true" 
  data-draggable="true" 
  data-decimal="0" 
  data-step="10">
//...
```

and your lifecycle hooks would look something like this

```js
componentDidMount(){
    this.nv.addEventListener("moved.zf.slider", this.handleSliderMove);
}
componentWillUnmount(){
    this.nv.removeEventListener('moved.zf.slider', this.handleSliderMove);
}
```

Comment: I assumed you meant `ref={(elem) => {this.nv = elem}}` by the way.  Doesn't compile the other way

Comment: Fixed my answer. It should be curly braces rather than parentheses.