# Mouse hold and drag without jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, events

I am using react and I want to be able to detect mouse and hold events without using jquery. Is this posible?

Comment: Yes, of course. This website will give you an overview about MouseEvents: [MDN MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent).

Answer (score 0):

if you're using React.js, try synthetic events:

`onDrag, onDragEnd, onDragEnter, onDragExit,onDragLeave, onDragOver, onDragStart, onDrop`

[React Synthetic events documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events)

Answer (score 0):

You’d use `componentName.addEventListener(“EventName”, myFunc)`

`myFunc` will fire when the specified event is triggered. 
Checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36181732/4040563) on stackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

You can use a react library that implements Drag and Drop.
https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd