# Using a higher order component to add event listeners per component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keydown, higher-order-components, recompose

I have some components in my app which are expected to handle some user inputs from the keyboard. For that I created the following function:

```
export default function withKeydownEventHandler (handler) {
  id = id + 1
  return lifecycle({
    componentWillMount () {
      $(window).on(`keydown.${id}`, evt => handler(evt))
    },
    componentWillUnmount () {
      $(window).off(`keydown.${id}`)
    }
  })
}
```

This works fine, but the handlers are being fired off for different components at the same time. So if my handler does different things in each component, whenever I click a button it will be fired off from both components at the same time. Also, once one component is unmounted, the HoC will no longer work.

For example, say I have the following two containers:

```
export default compose(
  withKeydownEventHandler((evt, props) => {
    console.warn('hi from Component 1')
  }),
  withProps(() => {
    // stuff
  })
)(Component1)

export default compose(
  withKeydownEventHandler((evt, props) => {
    console.warn('hi from Component 2')
  }),
  withProps(() => {
    // stuff
  })
)(Component2)
```

If I click any button throughout the app, I will get the following output:

> hi from Component 1
>
> hi from Component 2

On the flip side, once one of the components becomes unmounted, I no longer get any events.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get a keydown event handler through an HoC that can be re-used throughout my app?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, may I bring to your attention that your `id` is set as a global variable. Are you sure you want to have such a variable name as a global?

Secondly, you are binding the keydown event to the windows with `$(window).on('keydown.${id}', evt => handler(evt))` which explains your unwanted behaviour. You need to bind it  once with the specific component you want the handler to act to.

Finally, why dont you create a HOC class and add the event listeners conditionally? like the following:

```
// src/Hoc.jsx

export default function(WrapperComponent) {
  return class extends Component {
    componentWillMount () {
      const { onKeyDownHandler } = this.props;
      if (isKeyDownEventNeeded) {
         this.comp.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDownHandler);
      }
    }
    componentWillUnmount () {
      const { onKeyDownHandler } = this.props;
      if (isKeyDownEventNeeded) {
         this.comp.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeyDownHandler);
      }
    }
    render() {
        const { onKeyDownHandler } = this.props;
        if (onKeyDownHandler) { 
            // a "ref" callback which assigns the mounted 
            // Element to a prop "comp" whicu can be used later to add the DOM listener to.
            return <WrapperComponent ref={elem => this.comp = elem} {...this.props} />
        }
        return <WrapperComponent {...this.props} />
    }
}

export default HighOrderComponent;
```

Then

```
// somewhere-else.js

import highOrderComponent from 'src/Hoc'    
highOrderComponent(<Component1 onKeyDownHandler={() => console.log('hey, Component 1'} />
highOrderComponent(<Component2 onKeyDownHandler={() => console.log('hey, Component 2'} />
```

For more info on how check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180414/reactjs-add-custom-event-listener-to-component)