# addeventlistener for react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select lib. I'd like to use `addEventListener` in my `componentDidMount`, but unfortunately, when I `change`, `focus`, or `blur` the `Select`, the `window.addEventListener('change'/'focus'/'blur', () => console.log('test'))` did not triggered. Is there any work around to make a general listener instead of pass in each `Select` tag?

Comment: You could check this, possible answer for your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180414/reactjs-add-custom-event-listener-to-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React select provides this build in

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {

      onChangeFunc(optionSelected) {
        const name = this.name;
        const value = optionSelected.value;
        const label = optionSelected.label;
      }

      render() {
        return(
          <Select
            name="form-field-name"
            value={val}
            options={options}
            onChange={this.onChangeFunc}
            menuIsOpen={this.onChangeFunc}
            onMenuOpen={this.onChangeFunc}
            onMenuClose={this.onChangeFunc}
          />
        )
      }
    }
```