# React Native - Handle parent state from child component (custom component) without add function in parent

Tags: react-native, components, state

I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35537718/8943429), but I want to change the structur of code a little bit,

actually I want to set parent state from child component but ***i don't want to add any function in parent component***

actually the expected result looks like :

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state={modalVisible:false}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Child modalVisible={this.state.modalVisible} />
      <Button onClick={()=>this.setState({modalVisible:true})/>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {

  handler(e) {
    //handle parent moadlVisible state to false again
  }

  render() {
    return
      <Modal
        modalVisible = {this.props.modalVisible}>
        <Button title="Close Modal" onPress={()=>this.handler(e)}/>
      </Modal>
  }
}
```

so I want to make it easy to call the `child component` without add some function in `parent` to handle the `child component` itself, even for closing the `modal` of `child component`

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any connection between the 2 components at all, then you may have to use a global state store, such as redux.

Docs can be found here:

https://redux.js.org/introduction

Redux creates a global state instead of local state between all of the components. It does require a little configuration but once you have it fully integrated, you can handle your scenario. Also as your components grow, it'll be easier to keep track of state.

**Why can't I just use events?**

Quote in a question here..

[react.js custom events for communicating with parent nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21951734/react-js-custom-events-for-communicating-with-parent-nodes)

> The React way would be to pass callbacks down to children explicitly
>   via props — . There's no support for custom events w/ bubbling in
>   React.

The reactive programming abstraction is orthogonal:

> Programming interactive systems by means of the observer pattern is
>   hard and error-prone yet is still the implementation standard in many
>   production environments. We present an approach to gradually deprecate
>   observers in favor of reactive programming abstractions. Several
>   library layers help programmers to smoothly migrate existing code from
>   callbacks to a more declarative programming model.

A horrid way to do it in my eyes would possibly be to use  `Async Storage`

to store the key value, but I'm not going to suggest that.

Comment: I've read about redux, but it's mean my component only can be used for redux project right? actually i want to create a `custom alert` component using `modal`,

Comment: I'm not fully understanding your meaning of redux project? Redux creates a global store. You can connect your components to the global store, or/and you can use local state as well