# Emitting custom event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In Vue.js we can emit custom events along with a parameter like

```
this.$emit('bark', 3);
```

and then we can listen to this event on the parent component like

```
<parent-component @bark=handleBark />

handleBark (howManyTimes) {
    console.log(howManyTimes);
    // logs 3
}
```

How can we do that in React?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21951734/react-js-custom-events-for-communicating-with-parent-nodes does this answer your question?

Comment: @illiteratewriter Actually no :) I need an example of how it should be done in React or "React way". From what I understood Event bubbling doesn't exist in React, then how should we write this simple `bark` example in React?

Comment: So assume you have a parent and child component. In you child component you are doing some action and you need to pass that event or some custom value to the parent component you can use a callback function, is that what you are looking, If yes, i can add a sample snippet code. Let me know

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Yes. exactly :)

Comment: Sure will add the code snippet for the same.

Comment: Added @PooriaHan let me know if it helped you.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As @usafder, mentioned the way. I am just adding the basic callback function for an input field. So on the console you can see the current value.

Basically callback function is the way to get the data from the Child component.

**Parent.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

export default function App() {
  const parentHandleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Child handleChange={parentHandleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Child.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Child = (props) => {
  return <input onChange={props.handleChange} />;
};

export default Child;
```

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-moser-q7vmg)

Addition to it if you need return a custom value use like this

```
<Child onHandleChange={() => parentHandleChange(10)}
```

Because in this it won't call every-time if you want pass a value.

Comment: How would you pass this to a component stored in a variable? :) I don't seem to understand HOCs and how to pass that data through a HOC.

Comment: I don't understand how the second example `<Child onHandleChange={() => parentHandleChange(10)}` works.  Why `onHandleChange`?  Is this just a prop named `onHandleChange` or does adding `on` do some hidden magic? Or would the Component's return value need to change to: `return <input onChange={props.onHandleChange} />;`?  Could we also return a value from the child with: `return <input onChange={() => props.onHandleChange(10)} />;`?

Answer (score 14):

You just simply pass down the custom event handler as `props`.

For example if you have `Parent` and `Child` functional components. You can then define the custom event handler in the `Parent` component like:

```
function Parent(props) {
  const handleBark = (howManyTimes) => {
    console.log(howManyTimes);
  };
  
  // note below I am sending the handleBark method to Child as props
  return (<Child bark={handleBark} />);
}
```

and then inside the `Child` component you can simply call it as:

```
props.bark(10);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use [this library, Evento](https://www.npmjs.com/package/evento-react), that I created to replicate Svelte's [`createEventDispatcher()`](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-events) and Vue's [`$emit`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html).

You have to create the event emitter (named by convention `evento`) using the hook, and use the dispatcher as you would do with $emit by passing the name of the event and the payload :

```
const Dog = (props) => {
  const evento = useCreateEvento(props)
 
  return <button onCLick={() => evento('bark', 3)}>wof</button>
}
```

The parent Component will be able to listen to the Event as it would listen to a React Event: by using `on` + the capitalized name of the Component Event. The data will be stored in `event.detail`.

```
<Dog onBark={e => console.log(`barked ${e.detail} times`)} /> 
/* will log 'barked 3 times'*/
```