# React Ant Design form.resetFields() doesn't call onChange event of <Form.Items>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm having an Ant Design `<Form>` component with `<Form.Items>` which have onChange events. If the onChange event function is true I'm displaying extra content.
So in the example sandbox I created, when changing all the the `<Radio>` to Yes it fires the onChange event which is validated and then showing a div with the text "You checked all answered with yes".
As I'm using `<Form>` it is a form controlled environment so I'm using `form` to set and reset values. But when calling `form.resetFields()` the onChange handlers are not called. So the message won't go away as the state not refreshes. So I have to find a way to call a function from the parent component which refreshes the form values in the child component.
Using `useImperativeHandle()` for every field to update on more complex forms to call functions from the parent seems way too complex for such a simple task. And adding custom events to communicate with parent components seem to be a not very react way when reading this [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21951734/react-js-custom-events-for-communicating-with-parent-nodes)
Is there something from the Ant Design form I'm missing? Because this must be a common task. What's a good way to approach this problem?

**Link to code sandbox with an example:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-curran-dqvlc?file=/src/AntDFormChild.js

**Example**

```
const formLayout = {
  labelCol: { span: 8 },
  wrapperCol: { span: 7 }
};

const questionDefaultValues = {
  rjr01_q01: 2,
  rjr02_q01: 2
};

const AntDForm = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const handleResetForm = () => {
    form.resetFields();
    // now force onChange of child component to update
  };

  const handleFillForm = () => {
    form.setFieldsValue({ rjr01_q01: 1, rjr02_q01: 1 });
    // now force onChange of child component to update
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={handleResetForm}>Reset Form</Button>
      <Button onClick={handleFillForm}>Fill Form</Button>
      <Form
        {...formLayout}
        form={form}
        initialValues={{ ...questionDefaultValues }}
      >
        <AntDFormChild form={form} />
      </Form>
    </>
  );
};

const questionQualifiedValues = {
  rjr01_q01: 1,
  rjr02_q01: 1
};

const AntDFormChild = ({ form }) => {
  const [isQualified, setIsQualified] = useState(false);
  const [questionFormValues, setQuestionFormValues] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shallowEqual(questionFormValues, questionQualifiedValues)) {
      setIsQualified(true);
    } else {
      setIsQualified(false);
    }
  }, [questionFormValues]);

  function shallowEqual(object1, object2) {
    const keys1 = Object.keys(object1);
    const keys2 = Object.keys(object2);
    if (keys1.length !== keys2.length) {
      return false;
    }
    for (let key of keys1) {
      if (object1[key] !== object2[key]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {isQualified && (
        <div style={{ color: "red" }}>You checked all answered with yes</div>
      )}
      <Form.Item name="rjr01_q01" label="Question 1">
        <Radio.Group
          onChange={(i) => {
            setQuestionFormValues((questionFormValues) => ({
              ...questionFormValues,
              rjr01_q01: i.target.value
            }));
          }}
        >
          <Radio value={1}>Yes</Radio>
          <Radio value={0}>No</Radio>
          <Radio value={2}>Unknown</Radio>
        </Radio.Group>
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item name="rjr02_q01" label="Question 2">
        <Radio.Group
          onChange={(i) => {
            setQuestionFormValues((questionFormValues) => ({
              ...questionFormValues,
              rjr02_q01: i.target.value
            }));
          }}
        >
          <Radio value={1}>Yes</Radio>
          <Radio value={0}>No</Radio>
          <Radio value={2}>Unknown</Radio>
        </Radio.Group>
      </Form.Item>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since AntD Form is uncontrolled, there is no way to trigger `onChange` event by calling `resetFields`, `setFieldsValues`.
I think your goal is to show the message depending on form values, and the best way to do is to use `Form.Item`, which can access form state.

https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-form-item-based-on-other-item-ens59?file=/src/AntDFormChild.js

Comment: Your're a hero! Thanks. Two interesting facts why i didn't invesitcate further in shouldUpdate, one `<Form.Item>`only calls shouldUpdate if  `({getFieldValue})` is included in the `<Form.Item>` children and secondly and this is the most confusing part for me, when logging shouldUpdates`{(prevValues, currentValues)` when resetting the form `prevValues`and `currentValues`are the same. Which is why I thought it won't work.

Comment: Do you know why they are the same and it still works?